# git tf configure "A server path must be absolute"

Tags: git, powershell, tfs, tfvc, git-tf

**Command** (cmd & powershell) sample (servers and path names altered)

```
c:\code\git\svnImport> git tf configure http://server:8080/tfs/collection $/project --deep
```

**Response**

```
git-tf: A server path must be absolute: $C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/project
```

What is strange here is that the error message is puking back the local path to where Git is installed on my workstation and not the server path to TFS.

Windows 8.1 (x64)

Git 2.9.0 (x64)

TFS 2015

I've been beating my head against this wall for a couple of hours now... time to ask for some assistance! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is this: [$/project] ?

Comment: TFS project name which was created under the TFS collection. For example: the url to the project in TFS would look like this: http://{server}:8080/tfs/sandbox/{project}%20Team/_dashboards. So, the original should have looked like this: $/{project} so that it was more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Riaz Here.
Just try in this way Dear.

git tf configure http://server:8080/tfs/collection '$\project'

Comment: That was it! Oh, sometimes you just can't see the backslashes for the forwardslashes. Thanks!